# What is the benefit of being solid with Amnon Duul (Travel Hub)?

Tags: firefly

I was playing the [*Firefly* board game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/138161/firefly-game) last night and we realized that we couldn't find any particular benefit in Amnon Duul's bonus for being solid, specifically "You may load any number of passengers and fugitives at Space bazaar, no limit."

We couldn't find any use for said passengers or fugitives in the rule book, the only thing we could think of was if - while on a mission- a fugitive/passenger dies (perhaps due to the Reaver Cutter encounter) you can refill without having to do any misbehaving again.

Can you use passengers and fugitives loaded at space bazaar for anything other than re-obtaining those lost during completion of a mission?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As well as being useful in cases where fugitives or passengers die and you have a job which requires a specific amount of them, there is another case where being solid with Amnon Duul can be handy.

If you start a job like Patience' `Ranch Hand Recruitment` which states

> **Pick-Up**
> Load Passengers, no limit.
>
> **Drop-Off**
> Deliver Passengers. Get paid $300 per Passenger.

but you have some of your cargo hold filled with other stuff (requirements for another job, parts, fuel or randomly acquired cargo) which you are able to offload on the way, then you can top up your cargo hold with more passengers so that you can earn more on completion of the job.

Comment: It gets even funnier if you're running two jobs that have "no limit" loads (going in the same direction past the Bazaar). You can drop off a full load at one, jump to the Bazaar and grab a full load for the other. :)