# Passengers and Fugitives: can they be cashed in at a location, like goods?

Tags: firefly

Just as some Nav cards give you Cargo and Contraband, which you can sell to a contact for cash, some situations result in  you having extra Passengers or Fugitives.

I know they may be useful to keep in case they are needed for a later mission, *but is there any way to cash in on them at a location, like you can with cargo and contraband?*

Im playing currently with the vanilla Core set **of Firefly the Board Game**, but will accept answers related to the expansions, if its just not possible to "sell" fugitives or passengers in the core set.

Comment: Also see: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/15380/2246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in either the base game or any of the expansions to "sell" fugitive or passengers. [The FAQ](http://fireflyboardgame.com/howtoplay/FAQ.aspx) describes the only way to get rid of them:

> You may drop Fugitives and Passengers off in any sector with a Planet (you can’t toss them out the air-lock in deep space). This does not use an Action and can be done during another Action, on your turn.

Thematically this makes sense. Goods left over from a failed job or found from salvage still have value to others aside from their intended recipient. People however want to get to a certain place and won't be willing to pay if they wound up somewhere else (would you pay if an airline dropped you off at the wrong city?).

Answer (score 3):

In the *Kalidasa* expansion there are jobs from *Fanty & Mingo* where you Pick up a fixed amount of fugitives from one place, and drop off a variable amount at the destination. So you get paid per fugitive.

Comment: The base game also includes a job from Patience: "Ranch Hand Recruitment" which states "... Drop-Off: Deliver Passengers. Get paid $300 per Passenger."

Answer (score 1):

You may trade with other players any time they are in the same sector as you. You can trade as much or little as you both agree, for as much or little compensation as you both agree.

And if the Reavers just wiped out all their passengers and fugitives one sector away from delivering them for a critical job, I bet you could negotiate a really good price for those extra passengers you keep stored in your stash—er... hold, or wherever you keep them.